# Overridding a generic method in java

Tags: java, generics, overriding

I have a method defined in one abstract class as follows,

```
public abstract class AbstractService {
    protected abstract <T> Message<T> executeService(Message<T> msg)
            throws ServiceException;

}
```

I want to implement this method in a concrete subclass as follows,

```
public class RescheduleInfoAdaptor extends AbstractService {
    @Override
    protected Message<RescheduleInfo> executeService(Message<RescheduleInfo> msg)
            throws ServiceException {
        //implementation goes here
    }
}
```

But the compiler is reporting error saying

```
The method executeService(Message<RescheduleInfo>) of type RescheduleInfoAdaptor must override or implement a supertype method
```

Can anyone suggest how can i implement the super class method in child class with required type?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

*Either*

- Up-bound the abstract method type parameter to `RescheduleInfo` (or some specific superclass of `RescheduleInfo`, something like `AbstractInfo`)

For example:

```
protected abstract <T extends RescheduleInfo> Message<T> executeService(Message<T> msg)
        throws ServiceException;
```

However, note that this will compile, but will generate a "Type safety" warning.

*or*

- Make the `AbstractService` generic and remove the abstract method type-parameter.

For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractService<T> {
    protected abstract Message<T> executeService(Message<T> msg)
            throws ServiceException;

}
```

Then, in the other class, you'll have:

```
public class RescheduleInfoAdaptor extends AbstractService<RescheduleInfo> {
    @Override
    protected Message<RescheduleInfo> executeService(Message<RescheduleInfo> msg)
            throws ServiceException {
        //implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractService<T> {
       protected abstract Message<T> executeService(Message<T> msg)
```

and

```
public class RescheduleInfoAdaptor extends AbstractService<RescheduleInfo> {
```

Comment: That doesn't protect from copy&paste errors - Fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this

```
protected abstract <T> Message<T> executeService(Message<T> msg)
```

To this

```
protected abstract <T extends Something> Message<T extends Something> executeService(Message<T extends Something> msg)
```

Where Something is a super class of `RescheduleInfo`